# Recovering from exceptions in PHP/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, exception, daemon

I have made [a simple command-line tool](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) with Symfony2 which calls a service which throws a `UniverseException` in case of error. Sort of like this;

```
# /src/AppBundle/Command/UniverseCommand.php
class UniverseCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if ( 1 == 2 )
            throw new UniverseException('Strange things are afoot');
    }
}
```

I also added a `CommandExceptionListener` which can recover my application if a `MyAppBundleException` is thrown.

```
# /src/AppBundle/EventListener/CommandExceptionListener.php
class CommandExceptionListener
{
    public function onConsoleException(ConsoleExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof UniverseException) {
            // Reboot the universe
            // Continue existence..?
        }
    }
}
```

It works great!

But now I'd like to run the command as a daemon using the [daemonizable-command](https://github.com/mac-cain13/daemonizable-command) bundle. If my service throws an exception, execution is stopped and that makes for a terrible daemon!

My app has already handled this type of exception. Is there any way to recover from it and allow my daemon to continue executing?

**EDIT:**
I tried adding a `try`/`catch` in the command like so..

```
# /src/AppBundle/Command/UniverseCommand.php
class UniverseCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        try{
            if ( 1 == 2 )
                throw new UniverseException('Strange things are afoot');
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            echo 'The universe behaved badly but I rebooted it.';
        }
    }
}
```

It catches the exception and the daemon continues! But now, of course, my event listener isn't firing and the exception isn't being handled properly.

Comment: Maybe the command is somehow returning a non-zero exit status causing the execution to stop?

Comment: @nateevans I tried setting `$this->setReturnCode(0);` in my execute() function but no luck, is that what you meant?